# Data structure for a grammar checker for LaTeX sources

Tags: haskell, web-applications, latex, spell-checking

Let me start with acknowledging that this is a rather broad question, but I need to start somewhere and reduce the design space a bit.

**The problem**

Grammarly is an online app that provides grammar and spell-checking as a browser plugin. Currently, there neither exists support for text editors nor latex sources. Grammarly is apparently often confused when forced to deal with annotated text or text that is formatted (e.g.  contains wrapped lines). I guess many people could use that tool when writing up scientific papers or pretty much any other LaTeX tool. I also presume that other solutions exist or will soon pop up that work similarly.

**The solution**

In principle, it is not necessary to support Grammarly directly in, e.g., emacs. It suffices to provide a convenient interface to check multiple source files at once. To that end, a simple web app could walk through a directory, read all .tex sources, remove all formatting and markup, and expose the files as an HTML document. The user could open that document, run Grammarly, and apply any fixes. The app would have to take the corrected text and reapply formatting, markdown, etc. to save the now fixed source file.

**The question(s)**

While it is reasonably simple to create such a web application, there are other requirements to be considered: LaTeX parsing (up to "standard" syntax) and a library like HaTeX could deal with parsing and interpretation. But the process of editing needs some thought. Presuming that the removal of formatting can be implemented by only deleting content, it should be possible to take a correction as a diff and reapply it to the formatted document.

In Haskell, is there a data structure for text editing that supports this use case. That is, a representation of text that can store deletions, find diffs, undo deletions, and move a diff accordingly? If not in Haskell, does something like this exist somewhere else?

Bonus question 2: What is the simplest (as in loc required) web framework in Haskell to set up such a web app? It would serve one HTML document and accept updated versions of the text files. No database is required.

Comment: Well, something like [Darcs' data structures](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/darcs-2.12.5/docs/Darcs-Patch.html) would probably work well. But, I wonder whether your whole approach really makes sense... “remove formatting, run spell-checker on single block of plaintext, re-inject formatting”? Sounds quite hackish to me. What's wrong with just running the checker on individual chunks of plaintext that are there anyway?

Comment: And, yes, this question is too broad for StackOverflow...

Comment: Well, a grammar checker needs whole sentences. And sentences are often interrupted by formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing and then adding the text formatting, you could parse the souce text into a stream of annotated tokens:

```
data AnnotatedChar = AC
    { char       :: Char
    , formatting :: String
    }
```

The following source:

```
Is \emph{good}.
```

would be parsed as:

```
[AC 'I' "", AC 's' "", AC ' ' "\emph{", AC 'g' "", ...
```

Then, extract only the `char`s from this list, send them to Grammarly, and get back the result. Now, diff the list of annotated characters with the list of characters you got from Grammarly. This way, you only to deal with a list of characters, but keep the annotations.